# Django Rest Framework - object has no attribute post

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have this url in my urls.py

```
 path('foo/bar/api', foo.APIBar.as_view(), name='foo-bar-api'),
```

and in my view.py I have this class that hands the api:

```
class APIBar(APIView):
def post(request, self, format=None):        
    date= request.POST['date']
    person= get_object_or_404(Person, id=request.POST['person'])  
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And I'm trying to send this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'foo-bar-api' %}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                date: date.val(),
                person: person.val()
            }
        });
```

But Django it's giving this error to me:

```
AttributeError: 'APIBar' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

I don't know why this is happening. I used the same structure in other models and works like a charm, but this one it's giving this error.

Please, can you tell me what am I doing wrong? I spent some hours trying to fix this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `post` method's arguments arrangements are wrong, correct ones should be:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    date= request.POST['date']
    person= get_object_or_404(Person, id=request.POST['person'])  
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

BTW, `self` here means object reference. So it should be the first argument of an Object Method.